# How to get all checkbox values and put value of each one to a specific text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox with (20) choices and also (20) input fields , i need : when user choose one or more option, put value of checked checkbox in a separate input field else put (0)
I tried the following and it working when user chose only one option.

```js
$(".cont").change(function() {
    if($('.cont :checked').val() == "1") {
      $('#q1').val('1');
    }else{
     $('#q1').val('0');
    }
    if($('.cont :checked').val() == "2") {
      $('#q2').val('2');
    }else{
     $('#q2').val('0');
    }
    if($('.cont :checked').val() == "3") {
      $('#q1').val('3');
    }else{
     $('#q3').val('0');
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
      <input  type="checkbox" value="1">
      <input  type="checkbox" value="2">      
      <input  type="checkbox" value="3">
    </div>
    <input id="q1" type="text" >
    <input id="q2" type="text" >      
    <input id="q3" type="text" >
```

Comment: So if multiple are checked, you want the values in all of them, and then zeros only in unchecked boxes?

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the uses of `.val()` and `.is(':checked')`.

`$('#q' + $(this).val())` will select the correct `text` input.

`$(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val() : 0` will put your `checkbox` value inside your input if checked, `0` if not.

```js
$('.cont input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $('#q' + $(this).val()).val($(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val() : 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
</div>
<input id="q1" type="text">
<input id="q2" type="text">
<input id="q3" type="text">
```

Comment: Thank You , it is working and very simple code , but what if the ids of text input not the same value of checkbox . because i have some input fields their ids not the same value of checkbox.

Comment: @M.Gooda Show me what some others checkbox/input couples may look like.

Comment: I use some string functions to set the value of the checkbox to be equal the value of id , now it is working fine. thanks. :)

Comment: @M.Gooda No problem, don't forget to validate this answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps and use much more managed code to achieve this:

- Detect change on `checkbox` checked/unchecked
- Get the value of the checkbox and since the id of the `input` element
  is prefixed with `q` and the value of the `checkbox`, get the `id`
  first
- Use this `id` to fill the value in the `input` element.
- In addition, you can check for uncheck of the checkbox and substitute
  the previous value with `null`.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var checkedValue = $(this).val();
  var inputElemId = "q"+checkedValue;
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#'+inputElemId).val(checkedValue);  
  } else {
    $('#'+inputElemId).val(null);  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <input  type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input  type="checkbox" value="2">      
  <input  type="checkbox" value="3">
</div>
<input id="q1" type="text" >
<input id="q2" type="text" >      
<input id="q3" type="text" >
```

Comment: Thank You , it is working , but what if the ids of text input not the same value of checkbox . because i have some input fields their ids not the same value of checkbox.

Comment: @M.Gooda in that case you can have a custom attribute in `input` element with say, `data-checkbox` and set this value with the `id` value of the `checkbox` and then change you logic to detect element with `data-checkbox` value when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Comment: I use some string functions to set the value of the checkbox to be equal the value of id , now it is working fine. thanks. :)

Comment: Pleasure to help you at some extent